# Reading Metadata from Instruction

Tags: llvm

I want to extract all metadata information attached to a instruction.  I tried to extract this information using `getAllMetadata`.

Can someone explain me why the following code doesn't print the name for the metadata nodes?

Note: `I` is an instruction

```
.
.
.
I->getAllMetadata(MDForInst);

for(SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode*>, 4>::iterator II = MDForInst.begin(),
                      EE = MDForInst.end(); II !=EE; ++II){

      outs()<<"name: "<< II->second->getName() << "\n";

}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite inheriting the `getName` method from `Value` (and a few similar methods), `MDNode`s don't actually have names.

If you have something like:

```
<instruction>, !mymetadata !5
```

and you want the string "!mymetadata", you need to use the "kind" value - that unsigned value in each pair - to get the custom metadata name from the module. The code would like something like (roughly, didn't check it myself):

```cpp
SmallVector<StringRef, 8> Names;
M.getMDKindNames(Names);

for(SmallVector<std::pair<unsigned, MDNode*>, 4>::iterator
    II = MDForInst.begin(), EE = MDForInst.end(); II !=EE; ++II) {
  outs() << "name: " << Names[II->first] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: By mistake I deleted my comment!!

Comment: Thank you !! It worked!! Just in case: Can you give me a hint how I can fetch the values attached to a MDnode?

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer they are all contained in the MDNode's operands - use its operand-accessor methods to get them.